# build automatically nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

in my **client_controller.rb**

```
def edit
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  @client.build_address unless @client.address
  ...
end
```

...address is nested polymorphic attribute (1:1)

I don't like to call the build attribute in controller

#### my question:

is it good idea to automaticly  build nested object if it isn't build yet ?

example:

```
class Client
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable             #polymorphic
  #...

  def address
    super || build_address
  end
end
```

#### question2:

is there better way to do that ?

Comment: I think it's bad idea. That way you can't use `client.address.present?` in index view for example, because it will always build one.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, because you should only be building objects right before they're needed. It sounds like a client can not exist without an address, so you might want to be validating the existence of that association. 'validates_presence_of :address' on the Client model.

Comment: No, it seems a client can not having an address since he is building one at the edit action

Comment: hi, thanx for responses, the scenario is that I'll have several tables that contain address, so I decided to move this to polymorphic table. But imagine this address association more like if it's indivisible part of client(single form where you have client and address fields & same in show page). However user that is filling form may not fill single address field=> the address isn't created, later when he decides to add any address field via edit client, this association doesn't exist so I need to build it anyway,...same scenario in show action( to see empty address fields)

Comment: so main issue is that address fields are optional => I cannot do validates_presence_of :address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented like that in project form more than 6 weeks, still no problem at all,

so yeah looks like a good idea in my case, see question comments